# Project vector in epsg 3347 to wkt in Python using GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I am new to working with geospatial data. I am currently using gdal and rasterio to work in Python.
I have a raster with the following crs definition:

```
GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",DATUM["unnamed",SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST]]
```

I believe this is a WKT projection definition.

I also have a vector (geojson) in EPSG:3347 that I would like to project into the same crs as my raster.

I modified the below code from the GDAL cookbook, however it is not correctly projecting my vector. I would like to reproject the vector to the same crs as my raster and save the projected vector to my disk.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import os
import gdal

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GeoJSON')

# get the input layer
inDataSet = driver.Open("B:/Canada-d8-100m/Canada-d8-100m.geojson")
inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()

inSpatialRef = inLayer.GetSpatialRef()

# loading projection
sr = osr.SpatialReference(str(inSpatialRef))

# detecting EPSG/SRID
res = sr.AutoIdentifyEPSG()

srid = sr.GetAuthorityCode(None)

print(srid)

# input SpatialReference
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(int(srid))

#read in wkt projection from raster
ds = gdal.Open("B:/dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/15km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/CMC_glb_TMP_TGL_2_latlon.15x.15_2020052500_P000_Copy.grib2")
inSRS_wkt = ds.GetProjection()  
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromWkt(inSRS_wkt)

# create the CoordinateTransformation
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# create the output layer
outputShapefile = "B:/projected2.geojson"

if os.path.exists(outputShapefile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outputShapefile)

outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(outputShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("ProjectedPoints2", geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint)

# add fields
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()

for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# get the output layer's feature definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

# loop through the input features
inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

while inFeature:
    # get the input geometry
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    #print(geom)
    # reproject the geometry
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    #print(geom)
    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # set the geometry and attribute
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
    # add the feature to the shapefile
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    # destroy the features and get the next input feature
    outFeature.Destroy()
    inFeature.Destroy()
    inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

# close the shapefiles
inDataSet.Destroy()
outDataSet.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the python port of ogr2ogr that can be found [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py)